# Undefined variable in blade view using laravel 8

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I have the following view :

```html
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label>Pays</label>
        <select class="form-control select2-single" data-width="100%" name="pays" id="pays">
            <option label="&nbsp;">&nbsp;</option>
            @foreach($countries as $country)
                <option value="{{$country->name}}">ok</option>
            @endforeach   
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label>Ville</label>
        <select class="form-control select2-single" data-width="100%" name="ville" id="ville">
            <option label="&nbsp;">&nbsp;</option>
            <option value="1">Facture</option>
            <option value="2">Facture Auto-Entrepreneur</option>
            <option value="3">Contrat</option>    
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the followings Controller :

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use WisdomDiala\Countrypkg\Models\Country;
    
class Pays_Ville_Controller extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $countries = Country::all();
        return view('Casting.castingss',compact('countries'));
    }
}
```

My Route:

```
Route::get('/castingss', 'App\Http\Controllers\Pays_Ville_Controller@index')->name('castingss');
```

When I execute My code I get the following error:

> Undefined variable: countries (View: D:\Projet_Cast_Infl\resources\views\Casting\castingss.blade.php)

I could not understand how to solve this problem, normally I have already defined the variable countries in my controller!

Comment: Just for kicks, you could try passing an associative array to the view instead. Maybe compact() isn't working as expected
    
review view('my-view', [ 'countries' => $countries ]);

Comment: @ChrisL , I'm getting always the same error

Comment: Do you get a list of countries when dd($countries) in the controller?

Comment: where can I write dd($countries) and where can I see the result ?

Comment: First try right before the 'return view' line, and then try inside the template with {{dd($countries)}}

Comment: but where can I see the output ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233728/discussion-between-chris-l-and-ha-jar).